# Duplications of a list, with append, at each click on the checkbox. How can i avoid duplication?

Tags: python, sql, python-3.x, list, dictionary

[image]

If i check the checkbox, it starts a function that prints the data, including `score_home` which is a list of numbers in a dictionary, for example `(score_home=[0, 1, 1, 5])`:

```
Minnesota-Dallas:
Info_Matchs(tournament='NHL', date=8.1, round=9, clock='15:00', score_home=[0, 1, 1, 5])
and other matchs...
```

The problem occurs when I uncheck and then check the checkbox again, because the values in the list are duplicated with each click on the checkbox with `append()`. On each click, append() adds a new list by adding it to the previous list and i get `score_home=[0, 1, 1, 5, 0, 1, 1, 5]`. I would like to remove the list and add it to each click, or add it and update it, and always get only `score_home=[0, 1, 1, 5]`. I specify that the entire list is duplicated and not a single number

The problem should be this piece of code (below is also the full code):

```
for row in previous_results_query.fetchall():
    if row[0] not in test:
        info = Info_Match(
                tournament=row[1],
                date=row[2],
                rounds=row[3],
                clock=row[4],
                score_home=list())
    
    
    #Append Score_Home
        test[row[0]] = info
    test[row[0]].score_home.append(row[5])
            
print(test)
```

Note: `row[0]` is the name of the match (e.g. Minnesota-Dallas), while `row[5]` is the list of score_home results (e.g. 0, 1, 1, 5)

---

### **DETAILED EXPLANATION OF THE PROBLEM WITH OUTPUT**

If i click on the checkbox, the function starts and i print this `(score_home=[0, 1, 1, 5])`:

```
Minnesota-Dallas:
Info_Matchs(tournament='NHL', date=8.1, round=9, clock='15:00', score_home=[0, 1, 1, 5], score_away=[0, 0, 0, 3])
and other matchs...
```

Later, if I uncheck the checkbox, the function starts again
So I get this result. Look at `score_home` (`score_home=[0, 1, 1, 5, 0, 1, 1, 5]`), another 0, 1, 1, 5 has been added:

```
Minnesota-Dallas:
Info_Matchs(tournament='NHL', date=8.1, round=9, clock='15:00', score_home=[0, 1, 1, 5, 0, 1, 1, 5], score_away=[0, 1, 1, 5])
and other matchs...
```

If I click on the checkbox and select it, i get this result. Look at `score_home` again (`score_home=[0, 1, 1, 5, 0, 1, 1, 5, 0, 1, 1, 5,]`), another 0, 1, 1, 5 has been added

```
Minnesota-Dallas:
Info_Matchs(tournament='NHL', date=8.1, round=9, clock='15:00', `score_home=[0, 1, 1, 5, 0, 1, 1, 5, 0, 1, 1, 5,]`, score_away=[0, 0, 0, 3])
and other matchs...
```

**I want to get only output: score_home=[0, 1, 1, 5]**.

---

### **HOW DID I TRY TO FIX IT?**

I tried to fix it with a `try/except`. `score_home` was no longer repeating and the problem seemed to be solved, but looking closer I got the output `score_home=[0, 1, 5]`, instead I wanted to get `score_home=[0, 1, 1, 5]`. Tried like this, number 1 was removed maybe because it was a duplicate, but I didn't want that. I specify that without try/except, I print quietly score_home=[0, 1, 1, 5]

```
#Append Score_Home
    test[row[0]] = info

try:
    test[row[0]].score_home.remove(row[5])
except:
    pass
    
test[row[0]].score_home.append(row[5])
            
print(test)
```

---

**Code complete**

```
import sqlite3
from tkinter import ttk
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *
from dataclasses import dataclass

root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry("200x200")

conn_test = sqlite3.connect('sql')
cursor_test = conn_test.cursor()

#dictionary
test = {}
next_match = {}

#list
datalist = []

@dataclass
class Info_Match:
    tournmant: str
    date: float
    rounds: int
    clock: str
    score_home: list[int]


#Next match
next_match_query = cursor_test.execute('''SELECT team_home||"-"||team_away, tournmant, date, round, clock FROM Next''')
for row in next_match_query.fetchall():
    if row[0] not in next_match:
        next_match[row[0]] = list(row[1:])


#Function of the checkbox
def func_previous_results():

    previous_results_query = cursor_test.execute('''SELECT Next.team_home||"-"||Next.team_away, Next.tournmant,
                                               Next.date, Next.round, Next.time,
                                               Results.score_away
                                        FROM Next
                                        INNER JOIN Results
                                        ON Next.team_home = Results.team_home;''')


    #Create dictionary with class
    for row in previous_results_query.fetchall():
        if row[0] not in test:
            info = Info_Match(
                    tournmant=row[1],
                    date=row[2],
                    rounds=row[3],
                    clock=row[4],
                    score_home=list())


        #Append Score_Home
            test[row[0]] = info
        test[row[0]].score_home.append(row[5])
        
    print(test)


#Checkbox
Checkbutton1 = tk.IntVar()
Button1 = tk.Checkbutton(root, text = "Checkbutton 1", variable = Checkbutton1, onvalue = 1, offvalue = 0, height = 1,
                         foreground='black', activebackground="#d9d9d9", highlightthickness = 0,
                         command= func_previous_results).place(x=10, y=30)

root.mainloop()
```

Output:

```
Minnesota-Dallas:
Info_Matchs(tournament='NHL', date=8.1, round=9, clock='15:00', score_home=[0, 1, 1, 5])
and other matchs...
```

Thanks to whoever will answer!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/251189/discussion-between-barmar-and-takao).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand the code correctly you are filling the `test` dictionary with data from the SQL query.

And it is appending the list, because the first time you declare `test` is at the start:

```
#dictionary
test = {}
next_match = {}
```

Then the code

```
#Append Score_Home
  test[row[0]] = info
test[row[0]].score_home.append(row[5])
```

will append the `test`'s `score_home`.

I'm not perfectly sure about the intent here, but one solution could be to reset the `test` dictionary at the start of the `func_previous_results()`, like this:

```
#Function of the checkbox

def func_previous_results():
    
    test = {}
    previous_results_query = cursor_test.execute('''SELECT Next.team_home||"-"||Next.team_away, Next.tournmant,
                                               Next.date, Next.round, Next.time,
                                               Results.score_away
                                        FROM Next
                                        INNER JOIN Results
                                        ON Next.team_home = Results.team_home;''')
```

If this does not suit your case, please tell me.

Answer (score -3):

Perhaps, you could add an appended field to your Info_Match instance and only append if that field is false?

```
if not test[row[0]].appended:
    test[row[0]].score_home.append(row[5])
    test[row[0]].appended = True
```

Comment: Your code throws me an error:

     if not x[row[0]].append:
AttributeError: 'Info_Matchs' object has no attribute 'append'

Comment: This would prevent adding any new scores to the object, not just duplicates.